# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed when using jquery validation

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-405

I am new to coding, and am trying to build a website with a 'Contact Us' form, so, I copied a demo form using jquery validation.  Thinking if I could get this working, then I could add some formatting to it to make it fit in my website.  The problem is that the form loads correctly, however, when pressing the 'Send Contact Form' button I get the HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed error.  I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for any suggestions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#theForm").validate();
   });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Form Validation Using jQuery and PHP | Demo</h1>
  <!--  The form that will be parsed by jQuery before submit  -->
  <div class="layout">
  <form id="theform" method="post">

   <label for="firstName">Your First Name</label>
   <input class="required" name="firstname" type="text" id="firstName">


   <label>Your Message</label>
   <textarea name="comments" rows="5" style="width:535px"></textarea>

   <input class="button" type="submit" value="SEND CONTACT FORM" />

</form>

<?php echo $output; ?>
</div>

<!-- jQuery Form Validation code -->
  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

// Setup form validation on the #register-form element
$("#register-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        gender: "required",
        address: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        username: "required",
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter your name",
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
        }
     });

  });

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You have given no `action` for the form, so that means the browser will send it to the same address that this form is on – and if that’s a `.htm(l)` page (and not some kind of script that processes the send data), some web servers are configured to not allow POST requests for static HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

When you're submitting you're not specifying any URL. That means that the form submits but you should have a mecanism in order to post the submitted data in order to process the request after the validation. That's why you have a 405 error, that's because you don't have this back-processing.
You can do this using a JQuery AJAX call or a classic action attribute in your form. Since you're already using JQuery, I think that the first option is highly recommanded.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sample JQuery AJAX call that would work for me?  I am pretty new to coding, so don't know what that would look like.  Thanks!